# Pass entire data item vs just id as Prop in Vue list when using VueX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a `VueX` state that contains a list of items. E.g.:

```js
{
   operations: Operation[]
}
```

We need to display each `Operation` as an item in a list. So we have an `OperationList` component and an `OperationItem` component.

When it comes to rendering the list (`v-for`), would it be recommended to pass the entire item as a prop or just the `id` and have the `OperationItem` read the data from `VueX`?

Basically:

```
<operation-item v-for="operationId in operationIds" :id="operationId" :key="operationId"/>
```

vs

```
<operation-item v-for="operation in operations" :operation="operation" :key="operation.id"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say pass the entire item. That way your component doesn't need to know where the data came from and you would be able to reuse the component in situations where the data didn't come from Vuex.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a preference choice but in my projects I usually pass all the prop of the components that way :

```
<operation-item 
  v-for="operation in operations"
  :key="operation.id"
  :prop1="operation.prop1" 
  :prop2="operation.prop2"
  :prop3="operation.prop3"  
/>
```

I'm not sure if that's a good practice or not but in this case, it's more flexible, you don't need to give a structured object for it to render, you just have to give it all it's properties.

A bit like for a class constructor, I would pass all the necessary parameters separately instead of passing them in an `$option` array or `Settings` class.

For some components, it also doesn't make sense for them to be aware of the store, they should juste be "stupid" rendered components.

I hope it's clear enough that you get my point !